# Triggering a workflow from a incoming email account

Tags: workflow, incoming-email

All of the information I am finding on triggering a workflow from a incoming email seems to be related to SharePoint 07, and is unclear.

What account will the workflow run as? My best guess is that it will be the system account. All the information I have read just says it is triggered by the system account, but is it actually run as the system account or as the workflow author?

Do you still have to run the stsadm command in SharePoint 2010, or has this been solved?

If the workflow is run as the system account, can you use an impersonation step to downgrade the permissions? I.E. have it triggered by the sys account, but run as a different account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The last I remember, if the list is set to receive mail based on the permissions of the list, then the items show as created by the appropriate user and any workflows operate under their context.